# Ubuntu 16.04 stuck on boot Nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nouveau

My ubuntu is stuck on boot after I installed proprietary driver for nvidia 304, how do I reinstall open Nouveau drivers. I can get a root shell and network on boot.

Dkms status:

18192eu, 4.4, 4.4.0-173-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Difference between build and installed module!)

Comment: Any help at all would be great. Thanks.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu release? How did you install the drivers?

Comment: 16.04.06 I installed the drivers in software updates- additional drivers. The live USB had x org x server - nouveau display driver  from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source) + a second option 'using NVIDIA legacy binary driver - version 304.135 from nvidia-304 (proprietary, tested). I switched to the second and it got stuck on a cycle entering password after some graphics glitch. The card itself it writes is NVIDIA G70 [GeForce 7800 GTX]

Answer (score 2):

Boot into recovery using grub menu, select `root console` and run there:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
apt purge 'nvidia.*'
reboot
```

That will remove proprietary Nvidia drivers. There is no need to install nouveau. They have not been removed.

Comment: How on earth did that work? Selecting 'network' from recovery does the same as mount -o remount, rw  doesn't it? The only other thing I notice is when I tried to purge I didn't use the 'marks' what effect does that have?

Comment: However it worked thanks loads, you guys are magic.

Comment: The reason I attempted to try to switch drivers was a  attempt to get linux steam to work, shall I start a new thread?

Comment: This is really another question.

Comment: Thanks, saved my bacon  twice!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Here is how I resolved:

1. $ `ubuntu-drivers devices` 
    Run this command in terminal to get list of all the drivers. This will also give you the recommended driver for Nvidia to be used.

      Here is the expected output you will get:

   ```
   == /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
   modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001C8Csv00001028sd0000086Fbc03sc02i00
   vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
   model    : GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
   driver   : nvidia-driver-435 - distro non-free
   driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
   driver   : nvidia-driver-440 - distro non-free recommended
   driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

   == /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3 ==
   modalias : pci:v00008086d0000A370sv00008086sd000042A4bc02sc80i00
   vendor   : Intel Corporation
   model    : Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]
   manual_install: True
   driver   : backport-iwlwifi-dkms - distro free
   ```
2. Spot the Nvidia driver with recommended on it (In my case it is **nvidia-driver-440**
   Install the recommended nvidia-driver using this command: 
   $ `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440`
3. It should work perfectly fine after reboot.